# Bind (named) "no current owner name"

Tags: bind

I have really annoying problem with Bind and Cent OS, latest version of bind.

When I try to start it:

```
Error in named configuration:
zone localdomain/IN: loaded serial 42
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 42
zone 0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1997022700
zone 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1997022700
zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 42
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 42
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:3: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:4: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:11: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:12: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:13: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:14: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:15: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:16: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:17: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:18: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:19: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:20: no current owner name
/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db:21: no current owner name
zone x7-hosting.org/IN: loading master file /var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db: no owner
_default/x7-hosting.org/IN: no owner
```

This is myx7-hosting.org.db file:

```
$ORIGIN x7-hosting.org.
    $TTL 14400
    @       IN      SOA     ns1.x7-hosting.org.     root.x7-hosting.org. (
                2013010802      ; serial, todays date+todays
                86400           ; refresh, seconds
                7200            ; retry, seconds
                3600000         ; expire, seconds
                86400 )         ; minimum, seconds

    x7-hosting.org.                86400   IN      NS      ns1.x7-hosting.org.
    x7-hosting.org.                86400   IN      NS      ns2.x7-hosting.org.
    ns1.x7-hosting.org.            14400   IN      A       91.193.75.81
    ns2.x7-hosting.org.            14400   IN      A       91.193.75.81
    x7-hosting.org.                14400   IN      A       91.193.75.81
    localhost.x7-hosting.org.      14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1
    x7-hosting.org.                14400   IN      MX      0 x7-hosting.org.
    www                          14400   IN      CNAME   x7-hosting.org.
    ftp                          14400   IN      CNAME   x7-hosting.org.
    mail                         14400   IN      CNAME   x7-hosting.org.
    webmail                      14400   IN      CNAME   x7-hosting.org.
```

This is my named.conf

```
    // MAINTAINED BY [LUKA PAUNOVIC]
// Began [10.02.2013]

include "/etc/rndc.key";

controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { "rndckey"; };
};

options {
        allow-transfer { 127.0.0.1; };
        allow-recursion { 91.193.75.81; };
        directory "/var/named";
        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";
        dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        // query-source address * port 53;
};

//
// a caching only nameserver config
//

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "/var/named/named.ca";
};

zone "localdomain" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/localdomain.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/localhost.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/named.local";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/named.ip6.local";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/named.broadcast";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/named.zero";
        allow-update { none; };
};

// LOCAL ZONES /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// your websites and other named-servers will go below here.
zone "x7-hosting.org" {
            type master;
            file "/var/named/sites/x7-hosting.org.db";
    };
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove the leading whitespace from (at least) the first few lines of the file.

Comment: I do not have whitespaces on the top of the file...

Comment: Then please edit your question to reflect the actual state of the file.

Comment: Where do you see blank line at top of myx7-hosting.org.db file o.O

Comment: @Luka - `whitespace` does not just mean blank lines, it also means indenting

Comment: I do not care, I installed Kloxo, this is annoying.

Comment: I see leading whitespace before `$TTL` and every line that follows it.